# Cygwin - mintty.exe is stuck when I try to quit

Tags: windows, cygwin, icons, mintty

I'm running Windows 10 with Cygwin.
When opening Cygwin from the start menu (Pointing to C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico - and then entering "exit", the process gets unresponsive and I have to kill it from the task manager.

I tried the following:

1. Open a cmd (not elevated) and then enter the command as it appears in the shortcut. It does not start in my home folder (C:\cygwin64\home\david) but it exits gracefully.
2. Changing the shortcut to run as administrator - Cygwin quits gracefully but it's a hassle to approve the program to run as administrator.

Any more ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Any program that could potentially interference with cygwin ? https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.using.bloda

Comment: Try to run `mintty` as an administrator.

Comment: Hi @harrymc , I wrote in my question that running the app as administrator solves the issue but it's a hassle.

Comment: @matzeri - You are right - I have one of the apps listed in the page, disabling it solves the issue. Can you post it as the answer?

Comment: I have noticed that it happens on my laptop; although initially I thought it was SSD/HDD issue

Answer (score 1):

I have searched for this hanging issue for along time. The way I overcame this is by creating a new shortcut with target as **"%windir%\system32\cmd.exe " /c C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -**
This seems to have solved my issue for now.

Answer (score 0):

Malfunction of cygwin programs is usually caused by third part programs. 
Most Antivirus or unusual behaving drivers

A not exaushing list is available at
https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.using.bloda

If you have some of them you can try disabling or removing those.